# How to take some metadata to stakeholders of a different project, use Roslyn to inspect a solution, and generate this Output

Tags: c#, asp.net, console-application, roslyn-code-analysis

The end goal is for me to be able to provide some metadata to stakeholders of a different project. In that other project, we have various permission-related interfaces, and I'd like to be able to surface implementation details to stakeholders who don't have Visual Studio and who aren't going to go digging around in actual code. Having a way to get all the interface implementations across an application lets me present them in my format of choice. This will help stakeholders and business analysts understand what's been implemented. With a little help, they can follow the C# to understand what their app is doing. My hope is to close some gaps in understanding between expected and actual behaviors in complex applications.

Usage
I picture using this console app with a command line like this:

`RoslynScraper -s "c:\users\anyone\reps\MySolution.sln" -i "IPermissions, IWhatever, ISomethingElse"`

#### input.cs

```
namespace RoslynScraper.Models;

public class Input
{
    /// <summary>
    /// VS .sln file to inspect
    /// </summary>
    public string SolutionFile { get; set; } = default!;

    public string OutputFile { get; set; } = default!;

    /// <summary>
    /// what interfaces do I want to inspect?
    /// </summary>
    public IEnumerable<string> InspectInterfaces { get; set; } = Enumerable.Empty<string>();    
}
```

#### output.cs

```
namespace RoslynScraper.Models;

public class Output
{
    public IEnumerable<Item> Items { get; set; } = Enumerable.Empty<Item>();

    public class Item
    {
        public string InterfaceName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        /// <summary>
        /// class namespace
        /// </summary>
        public string Namespace { get; set; } = default!;
        /// <summary>
        /// containing class
        /// </summary>
        public string ClassName { get; set; } = default!;
        /// <summary>
        /// method or property name (or event or other member type, honestly)
        /// </summary>
        public string MemberName { get; set; } = default!;
        /// <summary>
        /// C# method or property body
        /// </summary>
        public string Body { get; set; } = default!;
        /// <summary>
        /// specific location in source file where Body is found
        /// </summary>
        public SourceLocation? Location { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am a bit uncertain about your goal - but finding the different interfaces sounds more like a Regex job - fast and painless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/// <summary>
/// Scans a solution for interfaces and extracts relevant data.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="solutionPath">Path to the solution file.</param>
/// <param name="interfaceNames">Interfaces to search for.</param>
/// <returns>Extracted data items.</returns>
private static async Task<List<Output.Item>> ScrapeSolutionAsync(string solutionPath, List<string> interfaceNames)
{
    if (!MSBuildLocator.IsRegistered)
        MSBuildLocator.RegisterDefaults();

    var workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
    var solution = await workspace.OpenSolutionAsync(solutionPath);
    var outputs = new List<Output.Item>();

    foreach (var project in solution.Projects)
    {
        var interfaces = await GetInterfacesFromProjectAsync(project, interfaceNames);
        outputs.AddRange(interfaces);
    }

    return outputs;
}

/// <summary>
/// Extracts interfaces from a project.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="project">Project to scan.</param>
/// <param name="interfaceNames">Interfaces to search for.</param>
/// <returns>Found interfaces.</returns>
private static async Task<List<InterfaceMethods>> GetInterfacesFromProjectAsync(Project project, List<string> interfaceNames)
{
    var interfaces = new List<InterfaceMethods>();

    foreach (var document in project.Documents)
    {
        var lines = await GetDocumentLinesAsync(document);

        foreach (var name in interfaceNames)
        {
            if (!lines.Any(line => line.Contains("interface " + name))) continue;

            var interfaceModel = new InterfaceMethods
            {
                InterfaceName = name,
                MethodNames = lines
                    .Where(line => line.Contains('('))
                    .Select(line => line.Split('(')[0].Trim().Split(' ').Last())
                    .ToList()
            };

            interfaces.Add(interfaceModel);
        }
    }

    return interfaces;
}
```

I've made some assumptions about the rest of your code (like the InterfaceKeyword constant). Make sure to adjust accordingly based on your actual implementation.